# Folder password with Apache and Nginx for external connections

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx, htaccess

I want to secure a folder with username and password. The password should only be needed when accessing the server from outside its network. (192.168.0.0/24)

I tried using .htaccess, but it ignores my `satisfy any`.

```cfg
AuthType Basic
AuthName "pw"
AuthUserFile /var/www/folder/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
Order allow,deny
Allow from 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0
satisfy any
```

I am not sure if the `Allow from` line is correct. Nginx forwards the headers to Apache, so the "real IP" is seen from Apache too.

Would the password protection easier with nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using nginx.

```
    location /folder/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/folder/;
    satisfy  any;
    allow  192.168.0.0/24;
    deny   all;
    auth_basic            "pw";
    auth_basic_user_file  /var/www/folder/.htpasswd;

    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    }
```